# Week Number for Actual Calendar Python

Tags: python, date

Can someone tell me how to get a week number in Python for actual calendar.

```
Ex: 2016-01-01 to 2016-01-07 = week 1
    2016-01-08 to 2016-01-14 = week 2
```

I tried 2 ways but none of them are working

1. Using `isocalendar()`

But that does not work for year end and year start week. For ex:

```
datetime.date(2016,01,01).isocalendar()[1]
# should be: 1
# got 53
```

2. is the following:

```
dt = date(2016,01,02)
d = strftime("%U", time.strptime(str(dt),"%Y-%m-%d"))
print d
# 00


dt = date(2016,01,03)
d = strftime("%U", time.strptime(str(dt),"%Y-%m-%d"))
print d
# 01
```

Both the ways do not satisfy my requirement. Is there any other library I can use to get the week number in Actual Calendar ?

Comment: Your question is not well-formed. You need to more precisely define when a week starts and when it ends. In your examples, the first "week" only contains six days. So one possible conclusion is that every week starts on Thursday, but days from previous calendar years do not count. I doubt this is what you really meant, but it's impossible to tell given only the information you've provided so far.

Comment: Sorry my bad its actually 01/01 - 01/07  -- 1
01/08 - 01/14  -- 2

Comment: You seem to have a non-standard idea of calendar week. According to ISO 8601 (cf.wikipedia: week) first of January was in week 53 this year. Even if you can compute it successfully according to your scheme, the number seems of limited value in communication with others.

Comment: OK, so you've corrected your two examples (with the help of @das-g) but you still haven't really nailed down the necessary information. You need to say explicitly what the definition is. For example, your examples are consistent with defining weeks to **always** start on Friday. If so, then 2017-01-06 through 2017-01-12 will either be Week 1 or Week 2 in 2017.

Comment: @guidot: I agree with you. However, there are a lot of folks (both in and outside of computing) who do not know how to think of weeks (or dates in general) rigorously or in ways that facilitate exchange of information. Thus, IT is often stuck with home-grown definitions for things. In fairness to OP, often these kinds of calculations are not meant for communication outside the company; it's more important that the people inside the company understand what's going on. And very often, these people are NOT going to understand or be able to use effectively an ISO-style concept of week number.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about actual number of 7 day periods rather than which week number you're in? Keep in mind in 2016, Jan 3rd is the first day of the second week.

If you're looking at which 7 day period, you should simply count days since the beginning of the year and floor div by 7

```
dt = datetime.datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=2)
days = dt - datetime.datetime(year=dt.year, month=1, day=1).days
weeks = days // 7 + 1
```

The 29th should be the first day of week 5. Let's try it.

```
dt = datetime.datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=29)
days = dt - datetime.datetime(year=dt.year, month=1, day=1).days
weeks = days // 7 + 1
# 5
```

Comment: I'm guessing that when you said "count days since the beginning of the month" you really meant from the beginning of the *year*, but I can't tell for sure since your examples are all in the first month.